# CSS Stretchable Text Input Using Images

Tags: css, image, textbox

I have just finished my PSD design for a website and am stuck at the text field.

How would I get a text field to maintain the size of the round corners of the background image?

Something similar to the sliding doors technique that you can do with  perhaps?
http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: rephrase the question, or draw something out

Comment: Do you need to use background images with rounded corners?  If it's just for a button, you could consider `border-radius`, which is supported in all the new and useful browsers.

Comment: I would like to use images because most people that will use this site are on older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text field doesn't actually need round corners, background images of the wrapping DIV elements do.

The "sexy buttons" tutorial will work - instead of having text inside the span (as described in the tutorial), drop in your input box. Set `border:0` and `background-color:transparent` for your input.